# ToString in Dictionary c#

Tags: c#, string, dictionary

I have a `Dictionary<int, string>` in c# and I need a way to create a string with its content with the format `"key1-value1, key2-value2"`, etc.

I am new to c#, so I created the following function that achieves this objective:

```
private string buildString(Dictionary<int, string> info)
{
    string result = "";
    int i = 1;
    foreach (KeyValuePair<int, string> pair in info)
    {
        if (i < info.Count)
        {
            result += pair.Key + "-" + pair.Value + ",";
        }
        else
        {
            result += pair.Key + "-" + pair.Value;
        }
        i++;
    }

    return result;
}
```

However, this function is inneficient and verbose. I know that C# has `String.format`, but I am not sure if nor how to use it.

Is there a better way to achieve the same output in a more efficient and less verbose way? If so how?

Comment: You shouldn't use `string`. Instead, use [`System.Text.StringBuilder`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/en-us/system.text.stringbuilder).

Comment: As you are using a foreach loop, the counter that you are using (i) is unecessary. A foreach loop will look at all items in the collection then stop, so a counter is not needed.

Comment: @DavidWatts In this code, `i` is not for stopping. On the last element of `info`, he want not to append `,` character.

Comment: @ikh yeah, seems I missed that with my quick scan initially. That is still unnecessary though. You could just have something like `if (pair == info.Last())` using linq. Thaks for catching my mistake though.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`string.Format` is to format `strings`, you have values and you want to concatenate them.

You can use `string.Join` like this:

```
var result = string.Join(", ", info.Select(kvp => string.Join("-", kvp.Key, kvp.Value)));
```

Answer (score 4):

Does this suit your needs ?

```
Dictionary<int, string> dic = new Dictionary<int, string>()
{
    {1, "aaaa"},
    {2, "uodhasdhsa"},
    {3, "audaygdyasgdyasdgasydgas"}
};

List<string> list = new List<string>(dic.Select(keyValuePair => keyValuePair.Key + "-" + keyValuePair.Value));
Console.WriteLine(string.Join(", ", list));
```

Comment: ..before only 30 secs!